# Google OAuth Consent Screen Verification status Not published

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth

I've set up a Google project so that I can allow my users to log in via Google. It's all working but in my consent screen section in the Google developer console it says Verification status: Not published

I can't seem to find any articles to explain what this means. I can find plenty of articles about status Unverified but nothing for Not Published.

I accidentally added a logo at one point which changed the status to Unverified. So then I deleted the project and re-created a new one and it's now Not Published.

My question is what does Not published mean? Can I use it on my website for login with Google or will it give errors or stop working after a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Verification status: Not published**

It means that the consent screen is new. When you create a new Google Cloud Project, you have to create a new consent screen, which initially exists in an indeterminate state about its verification status, hence the "not published" instead of "not verified".

When you add a [sensitive scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#oauth_verification) and save the consent screen (or upload an icon that the users will see on the screen), it has to be reviewed to ensure you do not have malicious intent, therefore the status changes to "needs verification".

After you go through the [OAuth client verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) process, the status changes to "published" in case of review success.

To sum up, there are three "states" in which a project verification status can be:

1. Initial = "not published"
2. Unverified = "needs verification"
3. Verified = "published"

---

Current documented [definition of an unverified app](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) confirms that leaving the project in the initial state if one does not have sensitive or restricted scopes should not lead to a warning screen:

> An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process

Comment: I'm a little confused. So will it change from Not published to Unverified? Is verification something that is needed no matter what then? Even though the only scope i'm requesting is the email address and profile. Even though it's Not published it seems to be working publicly at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it should be working. No, it won't change to unverified unless you add a sensitive / restricted scope or upload an icon. The "unpublished" is just the initial state of the consent screen, your users will see it correctly. I think I have to reword the first sentense, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Thanks. So as long as I continue to just request the basic email and profile scope, then the status will remain Not Published forever? This won't effect the user experience like the user won't see a warning or anything?

Comment: Good questions: 1. Not necessarily - I am not sure about what will happen if you publish an Add-on without sensitive scopes (but since you will go through the review, probably the "Published" status, as you are required to upload application logo at least, and that will trigger the "needs verification"), but i am not sure about that (you definitely won't get a "needs verification", though, if you just delevop and use the app without logo and sensitive scopes).

Comment: Second is easier to answer: 2. No, it should not. Users see this screen when the application requests sensitive scopes, see documentation on ["Unverified apps"](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865), so you are safe here.

Comment: I'm using it for my web application just to verify they have a successful log in with google. So I could just leave it in the current Not Published status and see what happens? although technically my application is published but the Google project isn't published but still lets me have the sign-in with Google flow. I am not using any API, just using the consent screen and the credentials for the OAuth. I'm thinking not to upload logo either that way it won't change to needs verification.

Comment: @Ahmed - yes, one of my project has a similar setup and works fine. If you have a Web App, then I think a more appropriate term would be "deployed", not published, therefore there is nothing wrong with the screen being "unpublished". Although I must add that the process is painless (albeit may be a bit slow), so you should not dread the "unverified" status

Comment: Not at all - good question, I don't recall that specific state of the consent screen being discussed before (although, if someone knows of a canonical Q&A - feel free to flag)